# Populating UICollectionView with images is returning nil : Swift 2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, swift2

I have a `UICollectionView` with a custom cell with an `UIImageView` in it as well as a custom class with the outlet

```
class theCell: UICollectionViewCell { 
@IBOutlet var theImage:UIImageView!
}
```

I have an array of `UIImage` (Which only has one constant image). The image is in the main bundle.

```
var tempImages = [UIImage(named: "placeholder.png" )]
```

delegate methods

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tempImages.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = self.collectionView?.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! theCell

    //Unexpectadly found nil
    cell.theImage.image = tempImages[indexPath.row]   
    return cell   
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by returns nil?

Comment: @AndriusSteponavičius fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: if it is a png you dont need to put .png

Comment: Didi you set yourcollection.delegate = self and yourcollection.dataSource = self?

Comment: @Totka I added these but it is still having the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have added this line:

```
self.collectionView!.registerClass(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

then remove this first and here is complete working code:

**CollectionViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    var tempImages = [UIImage]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tempImages.append(UIImage(named: "bg.jpg")!)
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of sections
        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
        return tempImages.count
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        // Configure the cell
        cell.theImage.image = tempImages[indexPath.row]
        println(cell.theImage.image)
        return cell
    }
}
```

**CollectionViewCell.swift**

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    @IBOutlet var theImage:UIImageView!

}
```

And don't forget to assign Identifier to your cell:

[image]

[Sample](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=54931416632010734498) for more Info.

Answer (score 0):

Try registering first in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`:

```
collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "FeedCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

**EDIT**

In your situation:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "FeedCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    let cell = self.collectionView?.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! theCell
    cell.theImage.image = tempImages[indexPath.row]   
    return cell   
}
```

Comment: For the nibName can I use anything or the UITableViewCell class name?

Comment: You have to use the `UICollectionViewCell` class name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is reinitialize `tempImages` array so it return `nil`.

```
var tempImages = [UIImage(named: "placeholder.png" )]
```